# Is there a way to make an attribute unkeyable?

Tags: rigging, bones

Can i make an attribute of a bone not keyable?, it makes me nuts that blender keyframes attributes that are supposed to be locked and makes my graph editor have way more curves than what i should be seeing.

Comment: you could right click and "add single keyframe"

Comment: or either.. create keyframes and then delete their source on the graph editor

Comment: yeah, but think about a character that has 100 controls, times 9 or 10 attributes, plus all the extras one adds... its really a very unneficient way to work, mostly when you want to block out your animation and use the whole character keyset, or LocRotScale

Comment: You need to create keying sets sot that only the attributes you want to key are affected. Read: https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/keying_sets.html?highlight=key%20set

Comment: so, i need to put all the controller's attributes in a keying set when all i want is to lock some attributes so they don't get keyed :(

Comment: [Keying set documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/keyframes/keying_sets.html#keying-set-panel) @ceg